# WatchKit: Handoff from Long Look?

Tags: ios, push-notification, watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible to use Handoff in Long Look from Apple Watch to iPhone? The use case would be like this:

1. User receives a push notification on his Apple Watch.
2. By raising the Watch he gets more info in Long Look.
3. If he needs even more info, he could take out his iPhone. On the lock screen he should find the Handoff icon of the main iOS app. By swiping it up, he can launch the iOS app into the detail page relevant to the notification.

I saw that the `WKUserNotificationInterfaceController` class has the `updateUserActivity:userInfo:webpageURL:` method. But couldn't find a definite answer on the Internet, whether handoff from Long Look is possible. So I'd like to hear your experiences on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a dynamic notification interface, yes, you can use Handoff from it.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/tips/ Under the "Use Handoff" section.

Comment: Thanks! On a related note, do you know whether we can enable Handoff from the **static** notification interface? That would keep our dynamic and static notifications consistent.

The current sitation is, when user opens push from Notification Center, only our static interface is displayed and handoff is not working with the iPhone. The weird thing is, Apple's default static interface (if the app hasn't done any customizations for the Watch) does support handoff, and even automatically.

Comment: @zavié "does support handoff, and even automatically" do you know if this is still the case? the handoff icon is moved to AppSwitcher but on my watch there is no default handoff for Apple Watch apps.